# Cypher query: CONCAT and TOKENIZE in the SET clause

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to generate a cypher query where I should SET the value of one property based on the value of the other property as like this -

```
MATCH (n) SET n.XXX = n.YYY return n;
```

So XXX will be set to YYY. But YYY has values like this - "ABCD.net/ABC-MNO-XYZ-1234" and I should eliminate all the special characters (/,- etc) and then concat the splitted substrings. So the logical statement should be like -

```
MATCH (n) SET n.XXX = CONCAT(SPLIT(n.YYY, "/")) return n;
```

Neo4j doesn't have any CONCAT function. So how is it possible to accomplish this stuff in a cypher query?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
MATCH (n:SomeNode) set n.uuid = reduce(s="",x in split(n.uuid,'/')|  s+x)
```

and run this query for every special character.

If there are a lot of special characters, write this query:

```
UNWIND ['/','@'] as delim match (n:SomeNode) set n.uuid = reduce(s="",x in split(n.uuid,delim)|  s+x)
```

Replace '/','@' with a list of your special characters.

Comment: Thanks @Mihal Raulea

Answer (score 1):

Your use case really looks like you want removal of characters in the string, and neo4j does offer a [replace()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/#functions-replace) function that you can leverage for this.

But in the event that you do want a join(), the APOC Procedures library has this among the [text functions](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_text_functions) it offers.

Comment: There's also `reduce(s = "", f IN fragments | s = s + f)`.